# Android Fetching public data of facebook using graph API without any access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/154810390/ does not fetch public data without access token. return error with code 104 and message "An access token is requir…o request this resource."

Though http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/154810390/picture fetch public picture.

Passing null to first parameter of GraphRequestObject() in place of access token returns same error.

I just want fetch name and profile picture of users by their ID even if current user is not logged in (dont have access token)
Gone through the docs but have not got any clue. any ideas?

Comment: The profile picture redirect endpoints are the only ones that don’t need an access token - since API v2.0, everything else does. You can not request any other user details without an access token.

Comment: @CBroe then how do i suppose to fetch other users data if current user is not logged in (dont have access token)

Comment: You’re simply _not_ supposed to.